# Removing XML format text from QnA Maker after publishing the knowledgebase every time

Tags: xml, azure, azure-qna-maker

Removing XML format text from QnA Maker after publishing the knowledgebase every time

1. Create knowledgebase in QnA Maker
2. Added a question which has XML format text answer. For Example:
   Q: `What is Status?`
   A: `<Action><Success>You have submitted.</Success></Action>`
   [Question-Answer format, I have added in QnA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jaOHe.png)
3. Save and publish the KB
4. Next time I have did some correction on same question text,not in the answer text. And save and publish it.
   Q: `What is Report status?`
5. I have observe that all xml format has been removed itself.
   A: `You have Submitted.`

Where XML nodes is vanished from answer?

No Code Available. Its Azure portal activity.

I have given the example on the step 2.

Comment: When you say Azure portal, do you mean QnaMaker portal? Are you using www.qnamaker.ai?

Comment: @KyleDelaney: Yes, I am using qnamaker.ai. Do you have any suggestion for this issue?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. The XML tags remain visible when I edit the question or add new questions or publish, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the QnAMaker portal doesn't display special characters well because it's trying to use Markdown formatting. To see if your XML tags are actually still part of your knowledge base, please try the Curl command in your knowledge base's settings page.